# Solvable $4$-transitive permutation group is isomorphic to $S_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I have difficulty  in solving the problem

> Show that a solvable $4$-transitive permutation group $G$ is isomorphic to $S_4$. (Finite Group Theory by Isaacs, $8$A.$10$)

There's hint here: Show a minimal normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ is regular and consider the conjugation action of a point stablizer $G_\alpha$ on $N$.

Suppose $G$ acts on $\Omega$. Following the hint, I only know that if $N$ is regular, then the conjugation action of $G_\alpha$ on $N$ is isomorphic to the action of $G_\alpha$ on $\Omega-\{\alpha\}$, which is $3$-transitive.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: All elements of $N$ have the same order, so it is a $p$-group, hence elementary abelian $p$-group, since it is minimal normal. $2$-transitivity of conjugation action implies $p=2$, Then $3$-transitivity gives $|N|=4$.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment is not quite right. It is true that $N$ is elementary abelian of order $p^d$ for some prime $p$. Then $2$-transitivity of the conjugation action implies $p=2$, $d=2$, or $|N|=3$. But the action acn only be  is only $3$-transitive when $p=n=2$, and $G=S_4$.